# Custom shadow mapping in Unity 3D Free Edition

Tags: unity, shaders, shadow-mapping, cg

Since real time hard and soft shadows are Unity 3D Pro only features I thought I will learn Cg programming and create my own shadow mapping shader. But after some digging I found that the shadow mapping technique uses `depth textures`, and in Unity depth values can be accessed through a `Render Texture` object, which is Unity Pro only again. 
So is it true, that I cannot create real time shadow shaders as a workaround to the limitations of the free version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If nothing else, you can manually calculate shadows using techniques similar to low-resolution ray tracing, then somehow put them on screen. I think this would be fairly easy, since unity supports hit detection with custom rays and all scene objects that have a collider, but of course this is highly inefficient.

If you can't afford unity pro (not even the student version), I suggest looking at other 3d or game engines that satisfy your needs better.